# why roundcorner here dont take effect?

Tags: mdframed

[image]

**It is still  rectangle**

this is my code(line15)

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 设有矩阵$A, B$, 则$r(AB)\leqslant min\{r(A),r(B)\}$.                                                                                     
\item 设有矩阵$A, B$, 则$r(AB)\leqslant r(A)$且 $r(AB)\leqslant r(B)$.                                                                          
\item 一个矩阵乘以一个可逆矩阵, 它的秩不会改变.
\item 矩阵的三秩相等.
\item 设有$A_{m\times n},B_{n\times s}$, 且$AB=0\Rightarrow r(A)+r(B)\leqslant n$.

\begin{mdframed}[skipabove = 10pt ,skipbelow = 10pt,leftmargin = 0pt ,rightmargin = 0pt,roundcorner=10pt]

\zihao{-5}\fangsong\color{Red}$[$注$]$: 可以把$B$分成$s$个列向量, 即$B=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_s)$, 那么$AB=A(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_s)=0$, 这里的$B$就可以看作$Ax=0$的解集.
\end{mdframed}
\item 若$r(A)=n$, 则$r(A^TA)=n$.
\item A是n阶方阵(下面几句话反正也成立).
      $$
      \begin{cases}
      1.\ A\text{满秩则}A^*\text{满秩.}\\
      2.\ A\text{的秩是}n-1\text{则}A^*\text{的秩是1.}\\
      3.\ A\text{的秩小于}n-1\text{则}A^*\text{的秩是0.}
      \end{cases}
      $$
\item $A=\alpha\beta^T\Rightarrow r(A)=1$(其中$\alpha\beta$是任意非0列向量).
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've met your request. There are some changes I have made to your code with severals `%%%%%%%%%%`. The (possible) reasons are into my comment below.
There is a little error: you should to put `\min` instead of `min`.

[image]

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}%%%%%%%%<---------------------
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}%%%%%%%%<---------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 设有矩阵$A, B$, 则$r(AB)\leqslant \min\{r(A),r(B)\}$.                                                                                     
\item 设有矩阵$A, B$, 则$r(AB)\leqslant r(A)$且 $r(AB)\leqslant r(B)$.                                                                          
\item 一个矩阵乘以一个可逆矩阵, 它的秩不会改变.
\item 矩阵的三秩相等.
\item 设有$A_{m\times n},B_{n\times s}$, 且$AB=0\Rightarrow r(A)+r(B)\leqslant n$.

\mdfsetup{%%%%%%%%%<---------------------
   skipabove = 10pt,%%%%%%%%<---------------------
   skipbelow = 10pt,%%%%%%%%<---------------------
   leftmargin = 0pt,%%%%%%%%<---------------------
   rightmargin = 0pt,%%%%%%%%<---------------------
   roundcorner=10pt}%%%%%%%%<---------------------
\begin{mdframed}
\zihao{-5}\fangsong\color{red}$[$注$]$: 可以把$B$分成$s$个列向量, 即$B=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_s)$, 那么$AB=A(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_s)=0$, 这里的$B$就可以看作$Ax=0$的解集.
\end{mdframed}
\item 若$r(A)=n$, 则$r(A^TA)=n$.
\item A是n阶方阵(下面几句话反正也成立).
      $$
      \begin{cases}
      1.\ A\text{满秩则}A^*\text{满秩.}\\
      2.\ A\text{的秩是}n-1\text{则}A^*\text{的秩是1.}\\
      3.\ A\text{的秩小于}n-1\text{则}A^*\text{的秩是0.}
      \end{cases}
      $$
\item $A=\alpha\beta^T\Rightarrow r(A)=1$(其中$\alpha\beta$是任意非0列向量).
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you tell me the function of the package and the options you add?And Why I failed to get roundcorner.

Comment: @shuboliang Yes, of course. I have read the documentation of `mdframed` package: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf (see pag. 2/3) framemethod=default and I have used TikZ method. After you can see the pag. 4, `\mdfsetup{options}
To set the options you can use the optional argument of \usepackage or you can use the command 
\mdfsetup which is not limited to the preamble. Inside a group the settings work only local.` See after also pag. 27 TikZ method. After I have added `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` to not have any error on clash color

Comment: ok thank you !! I have accepted and upvoted your answer and .i will refer to the document later

Comment: @shuboliang Don't worry at all :-) I hope I've helped you. My great joy is helping others. I have forgotten that you should put `\min` command instead of `min`.

Comment: ok i have noticed of that thanks